# Eclipse Code Format not working properly

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting

First i try this

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

which is not working, after this
I search online find different solution for code format in Ecplise for Java code but not working .

I prefer following links:

[Eclipse import conf .xml files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432538/eclipse-import-conf-xml-files) and

[Java How to beautify the java code inside Eclipse IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046576/java-how-to-beautify-the-java-code-inside-eclipse-ide?rq=1) of answers i followed, **Window->Preferences->Java->Code Formatter->LineSplittin-> Maximum Line length up to 120 or 140 symbols.**.

I also try this also

http://www.coderanch.com/t/105814/vc/format-code-Eclipse

then, all the above tricks not working then i made new custom like this, but this is not working also.

[Eclipse Java code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422640/eclipse-java-code-formatting)

I used all the above tricks, but everything not working.

My For loop also breaks in new line , like this

```
for (int j = 0; j < arrayL.size(); j++) {
    System.out.println("arrayL.get(j): " + arrayL.get(j));
    formResults.add(arrayL.get(j));
}
```

My Code looks like . [image]

Comment: The log statements seem to be formatted

Comment: What *should* it be doing that it's not doing?

Comment: Yes, log also be in new line, every thing gone in new line if I press Ctrl+A and Ctrl + Shift + F. Why this?